# Screen sharing default observer mode

Tags: screen-sharing

I have several `.vncloc` files what contains lines such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>vnc://10.10.10.11</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

e.g., double click on the file starts the `Screen Sharing.app`, and connect to the defined vnc URL.

By default it connects in *control mode* and I need switch manually to the *observer* mode.

It is possible to add something to the `.vncloc` file, to connect in the observer mode by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.vncloc files are simply URL pointers to the vnc:// URI scheme. This scheme is not standard and currently does not have a way to delineate the mode of the screen share.

Comment: Depending on which mode you are in when saving the .vncloc files (Control or Observe) the relevant <key>controlMode</key> stanza is set to either 0 or 1 and saved to the file. Yet these paramaters are completely ignored when launching Screen Sharing. Very strange behavior. Maybe in future versions these params will be honored.